# How do I embed node_modules library code into a single JS with TypeScript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, tsc

I want to compile my TypeScript project into a single file that *includes* JQuery so that I have a single `<script src="mystuff.js"></script>` tag in my HTML.  Can `tsc` do this?  Or do I need to resort to webpack or something else like it?

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "strict": false,
    "outFile": "chooser.js",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "sourceRoot": "./ts/",
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "include": [
    "ts/*.ts",
    "ts/*.tsx",
    "ts/**/*.ts",
    "ts/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

And my only TypeScript file looks like this for now:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.get('/salaries.csv', {
      onComplete: (result) => {
        console.log('result', result);
      }
    })
  })
}
```